# Performing an Update then Select Concurrency issues

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency

I have the following function which increments a value then retrieves it and returns it, one of the issues i am thinking i could face is between the update and select another transaction updates the currentVal value hence resulting in retrieving the wrong updated value, am i correct in thinking this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION INCREMENT()
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE newVal;
UPDATE table_x SET currentVal=currentVal+1;
SELECT currentVal INTO newVal FROM table_x;
RETURN newVal;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar issue, and it is true that another update or insert transaction will update currentval. The way I resolved the issue was to put the update and select in a transaction which will cause the table to be locked. This will insure you always get currentval.

```
CREATE FUNCTION INCREMENT()
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE newVal;
Begin tran
UPDATE table_x SET currentVal=currentVal+1;
SELECT currentVal INTO newVal FROM table_x;
Commit tran
RETURN newVal;
END;
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that in SQL. Here is mysql

CREATE FUNCTION INCREMENT() RETURNS INT BEGIN DECLARE newVal; START TRANSACTION; UPDATE table_x SET currentVal=currentVal+1; SELECT currentVal INTO newVal FROM table_x; Commit; RETURN newVal; END;

Comment: That is actually not necessarily true. Read up on "transaction isolation levels"

Comment: That is only if the isolation level is set to read uncommitted, and I believe that is not default. If it is, then I have never run into it.

Comment: Transactions doesn't protect against race conditions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805041/insert-a-row-and-avoiding-race-condition-php-mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795237/mysql-race-conditions